# iterating list of array-list and assigning each list to single dynamically created div in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am creating `div` dynamically ,and iterating lists inside `ArrayList` and I want assign these list to each div index-wise, means `div0` has `list1`, `div2` has `list2` so on.
example:
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ 
    s=doc.createlement(div);
    s.innerHTML=iteraing list
where all list comes on single div..so help me to assign it on individual div

```
s.innerHTML="<c:forEach var="i" items="${c}"><c:forEach var="a" items="${i}">
<li><c:out value="${a}"/></li></c:forEach></c:forEach>";
```

}

Comment: Post your tried code for reference

Comment: Above code is in JSP or javascript file..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}" varStatus="count">
  <div id="col${count}">
    <c:out value="${user.name}"/>
  </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: thanx....but i m creating div dynamically using for loop,so how to assign innerhtml to it...?

Comment: hi......@newuser ,thnx.i m creating div dynaically using for loop of java so how could i assign innerhtml to each div